# Airflow Python Branch Operator not working in 1.10.15

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My airflow test_dag looks like:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    default_args=some_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='0 10 * * *'
)

dummy_step_one = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dummy_step_one',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=dummy_step_one,
    dag=dag,
    retries=5
)

branch_test = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_test',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=branch_test,
    dag=dag,
    retries=3,
    retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5)
)

dummy_step_two = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dummy_step_two',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=dummy_step_two,
    dag=dag,
    retries=5
)

dummy_step_three = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dummy_step_three',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=dummy_step_three,
    dag=dag,
    retries=5
)

dummy_step_four = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dummy_step_four',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=dummy_step_four,
    dag=dag,
    retries=5
)

dummy_step_one >> branch_test
branch_test >> dummy_step_two >> dummy_step_three >> dummy_step_four
branch_test >> dummy_step_four
```

I am importing each of these python callables from another file, and they look like:

```
def dummy_step_one(**context: dict) -> str:

    return print('hello world')

def dummy_step_two(**context: dict) -> str:

    return print('hello world')

def dummy_step_three(**context: dict) -> str:

    return print('hello world')

def dummy_step_four(**context: dict) -> str:

    return print('hello world')

def branch_test(**context: dict) -> str:

    return 'dummy_step_four'
```

So in theory, this should run step_one, then run branch_test, then skip step_two and step_three cause branch_test is returning `dummy_step_four`, and then finally run step_four. The graph view of this looks correct:

[image]

However, when this runs, step_four is skipped as shown in the graph view above and the tree view below. Why?? Ignore the first successful run:

[image]

Here is what is printed in the log in the branch_test step:

[image]

***Important note:*** I was using Apache Airflow 1.10.12 and this was running successfully, but we recently upgraded to 1.10.15 in preparation for the upgrade to 2.0 -- so the issue I'm facing is likely related, but I can't find any documentation online that details a bug with the python branch operator in 1.10.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code has a bug in the pipeline logic.

`BranchPythonOperator` is expected to return the task_id to follow.
In your case you have:

```
def branch_test(**context: dict) -> str:

    return 'dummy_step_four'
```

which means that it will always follow to `dummy_step_four` and always skip `dummy_step_two`, however you also set:

```
dummy_step_two >> dummy_step_three >> dummy_step_four
```

This means that `dummy_step_four` upstream tasks are:

`dummy_step_three` in state `SKIPPED`

`branch_test` in state `SUCCESS`

The default [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) for tasks is `all_success` which means that for `dummy_step_four` the condition doesn't met as one of its parent is skipped thus `dummy_step_four` will also be skipped.

To fix the issue you need to change the trigger rule in task `dummy_step_four`.

For `Airflow< 2.2.0` use:

```
trigger_rule="none_failed_or_skipped"
```

(Yes this is the right trigger rule, The name is misleading which is why this was renamed in [PR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4NZj.png).)

For `Airflow >= 2.2.0` use:

```
trigger_rule="none_failed_min_one_success"
```

So the operator code needs to be:

```
dummy_step_four = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dummy_step_four',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=dummy_step_four,
    dag=dag,
    retries=5,
    trigger_rule="none_failed_min_one_success",
)
```

Example:

[image]

Noting: For your senario the `all_done` trigger rule will also work (if you prefer). I didn't use it in the example because the [official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) also use `none_failed_min_one_success` for this exact scenario.